# How to list Azure blob snapshots with .Net client

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In the REST interface for Azure blobs, when you request a list of blobs there is a parameter for specifying that you want to list snapshots.  Has this been exposed anywhere in the .Net client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.bloblistingdetails.aspx.

I think you want something like

```
container.ListBlobs(new BlobRequestOptions() { BlobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.Snapshots });
```

(Sorry if that code isn't *quite* right... don't have VS open.)

Comment: You got very close despite not have VS open.  It's more like Container.ListBlobs(New BlobRequestOptions() With {.BlobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.Snapshots, .UseFlatBlobListing = True})
(The snapshots option is only valid if you're getting a flat listing)